# Cannot insert explicit value for identity insert ID manually entity when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity

I have a table `Worker`:

```
 public class Worker
 {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Fathername { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string Company_name { get; set; }    
}
```

I try to add a new worker:

```
new Worker { Firstname = "John", Lastname = "Rambo", Fathername = "First_Blood", email = "Rocky@hh.ru", Company_name = "Survive" },
```

And I get error in application insights from last debug

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Worker' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1

Of course I can remove ID and it added automatically. But I want to add it manually of if it is nulled then generate automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your ID column will never be null as you are using the int type and not the nullable int type.

You can make your int type nullable by changing `public int ID { get; set; }` to `public int? ID { get; set; }`

The reason you are receiving this error is because `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to off on your database.

If you apply the following attribute/convention to the property in your class and update the changes to the database you should find you are allowed to insert into the identity column.

```
public class Worker
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Fathername { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string Company_name { get; set; }    
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the OnModelCreating overload as such;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>().Property(x => x.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about "?" symbol and would try it.

Comment: But I need ID to be generated automatically if it were not added by me.

Comment: I remade Worker and WorkerAssignment to int? but I have  if (!WorkerExists(Worker.ID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

Comment: It would be best to change if(!WorkerExists(Worker.ID)) to if(!Worker.ID.HasValue || !WorkerExists(Worker.ID.Value))

Comment: "Cannot insert explicit value" error exists  if I add only "?" symbol

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Key' could not be found  and 
The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found

Comment: You need to add a reference to the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Comment: Also please provide your logic for inserting a new Worker.

Comment: I already used it.     new Worker{ID=1434, Firstname="Superboss", Lastname="Leader", Fathername="Lead",email="boss@hh.ru", Company_name="dire"}, I want add it manually if I have ID

Comment: no and I not use  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] property. I just use [key]

Comment: Without using that the database will not allow you to enter a value into a identity column